# How to select random subset of cases in SPSS based on student number?

Tags: spss

I am setting some student assignments where most students will be using SPSS. In order to encourage students to do their own work, I want students to have a partially unique dataset. Thus, I'd like to get each to the open the master data file, and then get the student to run a couple of lines of syntax that produces a unique data file. In pseudo code, I'd like to do something like the following where `12345551234` is a student number:

```
set random number generator = 12345551234
select 90% random subset ofcases and drop the rest.
```

**What is simple SPSS syntax dropping a subset of cases from the data file?**

Answer (score 1):

After playing around I came up with this syntax, but perhaps there are simpler or otherwise better suggestions.

```
* Replace number below with student number or first 10 numbers of student number.
SET SEED=1234567891.

FILTER OFF.
USE ALL.
SAMPLE  .90.
EXECUTE.
```

Comment: Unless you already have a filter on, just `SAMPLE .9` should be fine. This is how I would do it though, unless you need a specific number of cases, then you can use `SAMPLE n from m.`